# Node.js URL POST rewrite

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, url-rewriting

I have this function in js file:

```
exports.authentication = function(req, res) {
   // ..
   // user validation
   // ..

   res.redirect('/login');   
};
```

How can I rewrite all POST request to different path, like /admin/*XY*, i.e. **/admin/login** instead of **/login** in my example? I now I can hard-encoded this, but I would like that *.redirect()* would automatically append this for all the POST request in all project files.

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't want to do Replace operation using text editor. Is is possible to encode this into Express()? I am already using url_rewrite for my GET request like this:

`exports.temp_rewrite = function() {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = '/admin' + req.url;
    next();
  }
}
`

but do not now how to do this for POST requests.

Comment: The redirect method supports relative paths: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Maybe this solves your issue already?

Comment: @masch, you are right! I was using "pathname-relative" redirects, instead of "mount-relative" ones. In my case the redirect should be:


**res.redirect('login');**


Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use this code and you can use same url after validation `failureRedirect`:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {    
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section    
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error    
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages    
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code to redirect all post request in your url .

```
app.post('^*$', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/postRedirectUrl');
});
```